# Custom Router Authentication Page

Tags: authentication, wifi, router, network-security, custom-pages

Is there a detailed tutorial on how to make a custom router authentication page for retail routers. I work in a small office and clients come and go and like to connect to our Wi-Fi with their laptops on a daily basis. Rather than giving them the 128-bit WPA password, I would like a single redirect page where they need a username and password to connect.

Comment: What kind of access are you providing? If HTTP-only: rather than having the authentication take place on the router, you could force all requests through an HTTP proxy and have it ask for login/password.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best off using the Open Source project [EasyHotSpot](http://easyhotspot.inov.asia/index.php/about).

Answer (score 0):

you can use radius or something like a hotspot, but that depends on what router do you have and if that router supports that...

Comment: Looks like my router doesn't support radius. Am I out of luck?

Comment: If you don't mind voiding the warranty and losing any kind of support from your router vendor, you could flash it with a custom firmware, like DD-WRT (assuming your model is supported). These come with additional features.